# Is there a 3rd party PS3 style controller for the Xbox 360?

Tags: xbox-360, controllers

I'd like to get a PS3 DualShock style controller for my Xbox 360.
So far I only see Xbox 360 style PS3 controllers, not the other way around.

Does anyone know of a PS3 style controller for the 360?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's also the modular [MLG Pro Circuit Controller](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0063BCQ1Q), which received some recent press at CES 2012.

It allows you to configure where exactly your analog sticks and D-pad are, so you could configure your 360 controller with a Playstation-style layout.

Answer (score 3):

Y'all pointed me in the right direction.

[http://www.amazon.com/Playstation-Xbox360-Controller-Adapter-xbox-360/dp/B0042SB2I0/ref=reg_hu-rd_add_1_dp](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0042SB2I0)

I found this one and it's only 15.00.

Answer (score 1):

From what I have found you can use this which converts a PS2 Controller to xbox 360.

[http://www.amazon.com/PS2-xBox360-Controller-converter-Black/dp/B0013UQ4KG/ref=pd_sxp_f_i](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0013UQ4KG)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can plug the controller in a converter box:
[Amazon Link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00569TQ8W)